# CakePHP Call to a member function disable() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, model, controller, cakephp-2.x

never use cakephp before and we have a project to edit for our client made in cakephp 2.5.

We tried to create a new functionality "Emplois" to add jobs inside the website. We mainly recreate what existed from an other models / controller already working inside the website but currently we get this error and we can't figure the problem.

```
Error: Call to a member function disable() on a non-object
File: /home/voyou/subdomains/labsurface/app/Controller/EmploisController.php
Line: 95
```

Here's the model :
`/app/Model/Emploi.php`

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Emploi Model
 *
 */
class Emploi extends AppModel {

public $faIcone = "thumb-tack";
public $order = 'Emploi.ordre';


public $actsAs = array(
        'I18n' => array(
            'fields' => array('nom')
        ),
    );
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'nom_fre';
/**
 * Search field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $searchField = 'nom_fre';
}
```

And here's the controller : /app/Controller/EmploisController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Emplois Controller
 *
 * @property Emploi $Emploi
 */
class EmploisController extends AppController {

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('get');
        
    }

/**
 * get method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function get($id = null) {
        if($id) {
            return $this->Emploi->findById($id);
        }
        else {
            return $this->Emploi->find('all');
        }
    }
    
    /**
 * get beforeRender method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function beforeRender()  {
        $this->set('faIcone', $this->Emploi->faIcone);
    }

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Emploi->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('Emplois', $this->paginate());
        parent::beforeRender();
    }

/**
 * voir method
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function voir($id = null) {
        $this->Emploi->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Emploi->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Emploi invalide'));
        }
        $emploi = $this->Emploi->read(null, $id);
        $this->set('Emploi', $emploi);
        $this->set("title_for_layout", $emploi['Emploi']['seo_title']); 
        $this->set("description_for_layout", $emploi['Emploi']['seo_description']);
    }
    
    
/**
 * page_plugin method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function page_plugin($page_id = null) {
        $this->Emploi->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('Emplois', $this->Emploi->find('all', array('conditions'=> array('Emploi.page_id' => $page_id))));
    }
    
    
    
/**********************************
 * 
 *    Actions administratives
 * 
 **********************************/
    
/**
 * admin method
 *
 * @return void
 */
     public function admin($search = null) {
         
        //(debug($this));
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->Emploi->Behaviors->disable('I18n');
        $this->Emploi->recursive = 0;
        
        $options['limit'] = 10000;
        if ($search) {
        $options['conditions'] = array('Emploi.'.$this->Emploi->searchField.' LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%');
        }
        $this->paginate = $options;

        $this->set('Emplois', $this->paginate());
        $this->set('searchField', $this->Emploi->searchField);
        
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->render('/Elements/tables/Emplois');
        }       
     }
/**
 * irre method
 *
 * @return void
 */ 
    public function irre($page_id = null){
        $this->set('page_id', $page_id);
        $this->set('Emplois', $this->Emploi->findAllByPageId($page_id));
            }

/**
 * ajouter method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function ajouter() {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->Emploi->Behaviors->disable('I18n');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Emploi->create();
            if ($this->Emploi->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Le/la emploi a bien été ajouté'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Le/la emploi n\'a pas pu être ajouté. S\'il vous plaît, essayer de nouveau.'));
            }
        }
    $this->render('modifier');
    }

/**
 * modifier method
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function modifier($id = null) {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->Emploi->Behaviors->disable('I18n');
        
        $this->Emploi->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Emploi->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('emploi invalide'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->Emploi->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Le/la emploi a bien été sauvegardé'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Le/la emploi n\'a pas pu être sauvegardé. S\'il vous plaît, essayer de nouveau.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->Emploi->read(null, $id);
        }
    }

/**
 * supprimer method
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function supprimer($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        $this->Emploi->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Emploi->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Emploi invalide'));
        }
        if ($this->Emploi->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Emploi supprimé'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Emploi n\'a pu être supprimé'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin'));
    }
    
/**
 * ordre method
 */ 
    
    public function ordre() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->Emploi->Behaviors->disable('I18n');
        $this->Emploi->Behaviors->disable('Image');
        $error = 0;
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
        foreach($_POST['Emplois'] as $pos=>$id) {
            if($id) {
                $data['Emploi']['id'] = $id;
                $data['Emploi']['ordre'] = $pos;
                if (!$this->Emploi->save($data, array('fieldList'=>array('ordre')))) {
                    $error++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error point to the line `$this->Emploi->Behaviors->disable('I18n');` inside the `public function admin` but from our understanding, `$this->Emploi` is null and we have no idea how to link the model to the controller.

Here the `/app/Model/AppModel.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Application model for Cake.
 *
 * This file is application-wide model file. You can put all
 * application-wide model-related methods here.
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Model
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

App::uses('Model', 'Model');

/**
 * Application model for Cake.
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your models
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package       app.Model
 */
class AppModel extends Model {
    
    function getNextId(){

        $next_increment = 0;

        $table = Inflector::tableize($this->name);

        $query = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '$table'";

        $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);

        $result = $db->rawQuery($query);



       while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];

        }

        return $next_increment;

    }  
    
}
```

Comment: I think it's not `$this->Emploi`, but `$this->Emploi->Behaviors` that's null. Should be very easy for you to check this.

Comment: I did a debug of $this->Emploi and it's return null sadly `(debug($this->Emploi));`
Also all other call like `$this->Emploi->create()` aren't working/same working

Comment: So, `$this->Emploi->findById($id)` also fails in the `get` function? Your original post made it seem that the error was very specific to the one controller function.

Comment: Sorry about that then, yes all `$this->Emploi->` return errors `on a non-object`

Comment: I never used Cake v2 (straight from 1.3 to 3.0), but it seems that this should all be okay. Do you have other controllers where the default model is loaded correctly? I wonder if it's an inflector issue somehow, not getting "Emploi" as the table name from "Emplois" controller. Foreign languages do trip it up sometimes. You might try explicitly calling `$this->loadModel('Emploi')` and see if that gets `$this->Emploi` set correctly. It's not a great long-term solution, but would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Sure I will try, where do we add `$this->loadModel('Emploi')`? at the beginning of the function or global for the class?

Comment: This look's to be working! If we add this line before the function there's no more error and the data is getting added to the right DB.

Comment: The question, then, is why isn't it auto-loading that model, because it should be.

Comment: Because as you suspected, [**the Inflector cannot singularize `Emplois`**](https://sandbox2.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=Emplois), it is based on US English. [**Custom inflections**](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration) can help, better yet don't use localized names.

Comment: Thx for the infos, your link is very useful, from what I understand, the main problem is that "Emplois" does already finish with a 's' so the singularize should also have a 's' ? If we would like to set "Emploi" as the base term where it's should be set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem with your code is that it uses non US English names, which violates CakePHP's naming conventions, and breaks the magic around that which is using inflection for tasks like finding and loading the default model for a controller based on singularizing the controller name.

Inflection mostly works on word endings as known from US English based words, it's not like the inflector knows about all possible words, it's just some basic grammar rules and a few exceptions, so things might work for words from other languages simply because their ending happens to match a rule. `-ois` as in your `Emplois` name matches the rule for uninflected words, it will catch words like `bourgeois` or `Illinois`. Regarding your example from the comments, `Projets` and `Projects`, there's no difference for the inflector, it will not match anything irregular, but just the the `-s` ending rule, and therefore being interpreted as plural, so it happens to just work by chance, so to speak.

Ideally you use proper English names everywhere. If you cannot work that out right now, then the next best thing would be to either use custom inflections, or depending on the situation where inflection is failing, interfer manually, like using `loadModel()` manually. An example for custom inflection for `Emploi`/`Emplois` would be:

```php
// in `app/Config/bootstap.php`

Inflector::rules('singular', array(
    'irregular' => array(
        'emplois' => 'emploi',
    ),
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Configuration > Inflection Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Getting Started > CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)**